# Why aren’t my HTML5 tags being styled in IE8 when I’ve applied HTML5 shiv?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I’ve got an issue with IE8 and HTML5. Despite using HTML Shiv, it doesn't seem to be resolved.

Basically the site is rendering fine on all browsers except IE8 & lower. In IE8 or lower the tags just get closed off and no styles are applied at all, ergo I guess the tags are not being recognized. However with the html5 shiv applied I can’t understand why it isn’t working.

(P.S. Yes I know similar questions have been asked. However they seem to be resolved with the HTML5 JS which I have already applied.)

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="_resources/js/iehtml5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_resources/css/common.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/yff7tzw.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Page Header Section -->    
<header>
    <img src="_resources/files/logo.gif" alt="" />
</header>
<!-- Body Section -->
<main>
    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>

</main>
<!-- Footer Section -->
<footer>
    <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the `CSS` is

```
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
hgroup,
nav,
section { display: block; }

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 67.5em;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#67862d;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:8em;
    padding-right:8em;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#67862d;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:8em;
    padding-right:8em;
}

header  {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:69.5em;

}

header img  {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:1.5em;
    display:block;
}

section  {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:67.5em;
    background-color:#000;
}

section p {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:8em;
    padding-right:8em;
}

section iframe {
    width:44.6em;
    height:22.8em;
}

footer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:69.5em;
    height:21.75em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#3d3d3c;
}

footer p {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#67862d;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:8em;
    padding-right:8em;
    margin-bottom:-0.8em;
}

    footer span {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}

footer img { padding-top:1.5em; }

footer h1 {
    font-size:1.6em;
    margin-bottom:-0.4em;
}

footer h2 {
    font-family: "museo-sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#67862d;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure IE8 is executing JavaScript?

Comment: @user2428118: good point. CloudSurferUK, have you tried putting an `alert` at the top of _resources/js/iehtml5.js, to check that it’s running in IE8? It looks like it should run, but it’s worth checking.

Comment: its always the simplest things! thanks @user2428118 Turns out it was java not running. Goddam these old browsers. Thank you both for saving me alot of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your security settings, Internet Explorer will not execute JavaScript in local files. An exception are files with a [Mark of the Web](https://superuser.com/a/94488/165611).

You can change this behavior with the following setting:
[image: Allow active content to run in files on My Computer]

If Internet Explorer has even more strict settings, it may not allow JavaScript on any web site. If that is the case, you can [enable JavaScript in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript) with these instructions.